# Libgdx - setting Sprite color

Tags: android, libgdx

Is it possible to .setColor(x,x,x,1) for a border of a circle like this:

[image]

else I have to use 2 sprites, and I already have 500 sprites referenced. Do not want to use a 1000.

Comment: Does the inside of the circle have to remain pure white while the border can be any color? That could be done with a customized shader.

Comment: yep exactly, right now I am using a blank circle sprite, so my game can dynamicly change colors, so I will look up shaders, but are they less expensive than just drawing another sprite?

Comment: A custom shader would be far less expensive, provided you can draw all your shapes in a batch without having to switch back and forth between custom and default shader many times per render. But you need to set up your sprites to encode the outline and inside parts into separate color channels. I can write an explanation later when at my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it in one pass with a custom shader, encode your source sprite in a certain way. Like this:

[image]

Now you can blend between white and your border color using the R channel as the interpolation factor. You can copy the vertex shader from the SpriteBatch source code and modify the fragment shader main function to look like this:

```
vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(vec3(1.0), v_color.rgb, texColor.rrr), v_color.a * texColor.a);
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks! This should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use two different textures, one with a filled-in circle and one with only a stroke. Set the texture of whichever sprite needs a stroked or a filled circle using the `setTexture` method in the libGDX `Sprite` class.

This is still efficient since the textures only need to be loaded once and by setting the texture of a sprite it only keeps a pointer in memory not the whole texture.

Comment: If using a TextureAtlas, there would be some overhead for reassigning the UVs over and over when using a Sprite. It would probably be better to create a class that doesn't subclass TextureRegion or Sprite but rather draws itself with a passed in TextureRegion instance.

Comment: Well what if I use just 2 textures .png files for this 2 different textures? And the textureRegion for the animations any everything else. Would it be sufficient?

Comment: Because I could also just reference 2 Sprite's and then just keep changing their positions in the draw method. I chose to create 100s of sprites, because it's easier to look at and it does not seem to be any difference in performance.

Comment: If performance is fine on the lowest end device you want to support, then this is fine. I suppose it could run the battery down faster to be drawing hundreds of separate textures per frame instead of batching them but I don't really know if it's significant.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the TextureRegion idea above and when you've finished your game, IF your having performance issues THEN and only then would i really worry about this, but im somewhat scared of shaders.

Most people never finish their games because they get caught up in the details way before they really need to.